# A way to syncronize data in sql express

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, sql-server-express

I have 2 servers, one with SQL standard and the second one is express.
I wanted to know if there is any tool or any way to synchronized the databases and making it work like replication without the replication (because i don't have the agent in the express edition of corse).
Thanks.

Comment: Create an SSIS package in the Standard Edition and use that to sync.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Windows Synchronization Manager

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151193(v=sql.105).aspx

Windows Synchronization Manager is a utility available with Microsoft Windows 2000 and later versions. If Microsoft SQL Server is running on the same computer as Synchronization Manager, you can do the following:

```
Synchronize a subscription.

Reinitialize a subscription.

Remove a subscription.
```

It is particularly useful for synchronizing subscriptions on SQL Server Express, because this version of SQL Server does not include SQL Server Agent, which, by default, runs the replication agents on other versions of SQL Server.

Comment: As i said it's 2 different servers.
will it work on 2 different servers ?

Comment: From what I can tell from the information in the link, the only requirement is that the Windows Synchronization manager needs to run on the same computer as Sql Express.  I don't see anywhere in the documentation that says the publisher and subscriber need to be on the same server.  You'll obviously have to read through the documentation and test it out

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151863(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Either script the replication subscription to run on the Express server, or use a Push Subscription, where all the agents run on the Distributor (which has SQL Agent).

See this [sample](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2012/11/16/synchronizing-a-transactional-replication-subscription-from-powershell/) for how to synchronize a Transactional Replication subscription from PowerShell.